# Is it possible to run dev_appserver.py with the remote datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm developing a web app with Google's AppEngine. I'd like to iterate on the code locally using `dev_appserver.py`. But it's hard to do this without all the data in my deployed app's datastore. I currently run a script to populate the local datastore, but it takes on the order of 15-20 minutes to populate.

Is it possible for `dev_appserver.py` to connect to my deployed app's datastore?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, it is possible.

First, turn on remote-api in app.yaml and deploy the application on production.

```
builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

Then, for example in appengine_config.py:

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
from google.appengine.datastore.entity_pb import Reference

remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi(app_id=None, path='/_ah/remote_api',
                                   auth_func=lambda: ('email', 'password'),
                                   servername='appid.appspot.com')

if os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Development'):
  Reference.app = lambda *args: os.environ['APPLICATION_ID'].replace('dev~', 's~')
```

If you have old application ID you may need to edit .replace('dev'...) part.

Comment: Dmitry, I upvoted your answer because think it is better than my own!  I'll leave my answer standing though in case somebody wants to consider different approaches.

Comment: Read this before you use remote API. https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api?csw=1

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm having trouble getting this to work, however. Whenever I access the datastore, I get one of these errors:
 File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py", line 2099, in ReferenceToKeyValue
    key.app(), key.name_space()]
TypeError: <lambda>() takes no arguments (1 given)

OR

BadRequestError: app s~foo cannot access app dev~foo's data. Suggestions?

Comment: Try to use "lambda *args:" instead of "lambda:" in the last line. I can see second error time to time too.. Need some another way to change app id here.

Comment: I traced the "cannot accees app dev~foo's data" error back to memcache. I added a flag to toggle whether memcache is used and turned it off in development mode. This made the errors go away.

Comment: After some more testing, that wasn't entirely true -- I'm still seeing the data ownership error with memcache disabled, just less frequently.

Comment: Just want to confirm, It is not working for me. When I looked at the post date it is near about 2years ago. So is it still working now?

Comment: This is not working anymore because of ClientLogin has been officially deprecated. https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps
This part is needed because of authentication

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible using [Google Cloud Datastore](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_python/).  You will need a flag in your application to control which datastore you are using at any particular time, and an additional set of data model classes as an interface to the Cloud Datastore instance.