# Where to put the remote_api in a local client sample code?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to use the remote datastore with my website running on localhost.

According to this, it should be quite straight forward: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi#using_the_remote_api_in_a_local_client

but where in my project should I place the code ?

I am running python 2.7 on Mac OS X.

thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote API could be used either from remote or from local. Put the sample code in a script where you  want to invoke remote API locally.

Comment: I want to use it as the general datastore for my project instead of the local datastore on my machine. But I don't know how to use the sample code. Should I put it in main.py or models.py or somewhere else ? Thanks

Comment: @ThomasD I think it's a good idea to put it in the main.py since the main logic is in it.

Comment: I am getting closer to a solution based on your comment and other questions here on SO. In my app.yaml I have defined a handler for my apis: 
- url: /api/.*
  script: api.py
and for everything else:
- url: .*
  script: main.py

Right now I have added the code to both api.py and main.py. Is there a way I can only add the code once and it will then be for both api.py and main.py?

Comment: @ThomasD Of course. You can add it as a function in main.py and then import it to any other module you want, like api.py and use it.

Comment: ok, but I still need to reference it in both? There is no "super"-class where I can place the code ? Sorry if it is a basic python question, but I am still learning :-)

Comment: @ThomasD No need to have a super class. Just need to put main.py and api.py in the same folder so that you can successfully import it to the local namespace.

Comment: put it once in appengine_config.py. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214258/is-it-possible-to-run-dev-appserver-py-with-the-remote-datastore